# Symfony2 changing the values of an item and saving them back in backend

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I need to create a function that changes a value that it gets from the backend and sends the new value back to the backend...

This is what I created so far. I get the current stock of the product(which is 50 in my example): then I simply check if the stock is larger than the quantity of the product and if it is I increase that quantity by 1, and remove 1 value from the stock. At the end I save the cart and I save the new stock(I think). However this does not work and I am still having 50 in my stock.

```
public function addAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->find($id);       
        $qtyAvailable = $product->getStock();
       // check the cart
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $cart = $session->get('cart', array());

          if( isset($cart[$id]) ) {  // Check if the array has this productId

                if ( $qtyAvailable > $cart[ $id ]) { 
                    $cart[ $id ] = $cart[ $id ] + 1;
                    $qtyAvailable = $qtyAvailable - 1;
                } else {

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cart'));
            }


        } else {
            // if it doesnt make it 1
            $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
            $cart[$id] = 1;
        }
        $product->setStock('qtyAvailable', $qtyAvailable);
        $session->set('cart', $cart);
        return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('cart') );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you just need to give the value to a doctrine entity setter.

```
$product->setStock('qtyAvailable', $qtyAvailable);
```

should be

```
$product->setStock($qtyAvailable);
```

if you don't have any custom code in setStock() method.

Also, you need to call

```
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush(); // this runs the query on the database.
```

after you set the new stock.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to add a :

```
$em->persist($product);

$em->flush();
```

in order to save the changes you've made to the product object ?